# Errno::ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redmine

Whenever I create a new issue in redmine,I get Redmine internal error page.When i checked in Production log it shows below code.

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1456.4ms

Errno::ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer):
  app/controllers/issues_controller.rb:173:in `block (2 levels) in create'
  app/controllers/issues_controller.rb:173:in `block in create'
  app/controllers/issues_controller.rb:152:in `create'
```

As i click on Create button it will redirect to

Internal error

An error occurred on the page you were trying to access.
If you continue to experience problems please contact your Redmine administrator for assistance.

If you are the Redmine administrator, check your log files for details about the error.

Back

```
 Redmine version                2.5.0.stable
  Ruby version                   1.9.3-p545 (2014-02-24) [x86_64-linux]
  Rails version                  3.2.17
```

Comment: update your question with create action and more error logs

Comment: Please tel me how to solve

Comment: Below is the version                                                                                        Redmine version                2.5.0.stable
  Ruby version                   1.9.3-p545 (2014-02-24) [x86_64-linux]
  Rails version                  3.2.17